# Finding the raw offset of .text section in a PE file

Tags: c, binaryfiles, portable-executable, ida

In IDA the `.text` section begins at `0x01001630`.

In the file, these bytes are located at a raw offset of `0xA30`.

The `PointerToRawData` field in the Section Table for the `.text` segment is `0x400`, which is the distance between `0xA30` and `0x630`.

I'm not sure how to get `0xA30` from the file headers of a PE file.  Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Weird. Could You show that PE file or provide some more information about it's origins?

Comment: It is just calc.exe on Windows 7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first 0x630 bytes of the .text section is the IAT (import address table) which IDA has converted to a new section `.idata`:

```
1000 [     630] RVA [size] of Import Address Table Directory

Name   Start    End      
----   -----    ---      
HEADER 01000000 01001000 
.idata 01001000 01001630   <- added by IDA
.text  01001630 01054000 
.idata 01054000 01054004   <- added by IDA
.data  01054004 01059000
```

If you uncheck `[x] Make imports segment` in the initial load dialog, you'll get the unmodified section table:

```
Name   Start    End      
----   -----    ---      
HEADER 01000000 01001000 
.text  01001000 01054000 
.data  01054000 01059000
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is a case of IDA trying to be clever. The `.text` section does actually start at file offset `0x400` (RVA `0x1000`). IDA realises that the start of the `.text` section contains api import data, so it changes the section name to `.idata`. If you have a look at all the section names in the PE header, you will see that there is no `.idata` section.
 Take a look at the entire PE header. You will see the import address table starts at RVA `0x1000` and has a size of, you guessed it, `0x630`.